# QGIS v3.10 GRASS plugin on MacOS for hydrology

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, mac

Installed QGIS 3.4 and then 3.10, both gave errors "Grass was not found in `/usr/local/opt/osgeo-grass/grass-base"` In both cases the directory `/usr/local/opt/osgeo-grass/` did not actually exist. I tried manually installing grass both with brew install and Grass 7.7 from grass-7.7dev.dmg.zip from the website. I tried setting the path for grass in QGIS to `/Applications/GRASS-7.7.app` and a few other locations that I forgot now.

All I need to do is create a flow accumulation raster from a DEM I have. I tried using the SAGA plugin in QGIS and that failed, wasn't able to generate a raster. I feel like my plugins have not been compiled correctly. However the base QGIS raster analysis works: I could create slope, aspect rasters sucessfully. The contents of my `/usr/local/opt` are currently

`ant            lcms2           osgeo-libgeotiff
ant@1.10        libcryptopp     osgeo-libkml
armadillo       libdap          osgeo-libspatialite
arpack          libev           osgeo-netcdf
boost           libevent        osgeo-postgresql
boost@1.71      libffi          osgeo-proj
brotli          libiconv        pcre
c-ares          libidn          pcre1
cfitsio         libidn2         perl
cgal            libjpeg         perl@5.30
cryptopp        libjpeg-turbo       pkg-config
curl-openssl        libjpg          pkgconfig
eigen           libkml-dev      popt
epsilon         libmetalink     python
expat           libmpc          python2
fftw            libpng          python3
freexl          libpq           python@2
gcc         libssh2         python@3
gcc@9           libtiff         pzstd
gdal2           libtool         qhull
gdbm            libunistring        readline
geos            libxml2         rtmpdump
gettext         libzip          sfcgal
giflib          little-cms2     sqlite
glib            mdbtools        sqlite3
gmp         mpfr            swig
hdf4            nghttp2         swig@4
hdf5            numpy           swig@4.0
hdf5@1.10       numpy@1.17      szip
hwloc           open-mpi        tcl-tk
icu4c           openblas        unixodbc
isl         openjpeg        webp
jansson         openldap        wget
jasper          openmpi         xerces-c
jemalloc        openssl         xz
jpeg            openssl@1.0     zlib
jpeg-turbo      openssl@1.1     zstd
json-c          osgeo-gdal
krb5            osgeo-hdf4`

Answer (score 0):

I set the path to `/Applications/GRASS-7.7.app/Contents/Resources` and it seems to work

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, still got the error ```"Grass was not found in /usr/local/opt/osgeo-grass/grass-base"```